# Product / patch installation or server upgrade required error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Hope everyone is doing well.

I actually getting these error from central administration and health analyzer rules

> Title   Product / patch installation or server upgrade required.
>
> Severity   1 - Error
>
> Category   Configuration
>
> Explanation    All required products must be installed on all servers
>   in the farm, and all products should have the same patching and
>   upgrade level across the farm.
>
> Server SEE-SRV-12 is missing a required product or patch installation.
>   Without the installation, the server is not in a supported state.
>
> Remedy    On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for
>   Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit
>   Edition" (15.0.4675.1000) from
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB2899512) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899512.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2883055) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4665.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883055.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2863837) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4631.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863837.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910906) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910906.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB2899512) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2899512.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2910910) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910910.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2889930) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4659.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889930.
>
> On server SEE-SRV-12, install the patch "Security Update for Microsoft
>   SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2883050) 64-Bit Edition"
>   (15.0.4675.1000) from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883050. For
>   more information about this rule, see
>   "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142700".
>
> Failing Servers
>
> Failing Services    SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)
>
> Rule Settings   View
>
> Version: 1296.0   Created at 5/25/2013 12:00 AM  by No presence
>   informationNo presence informationSystem Account    Last modified at
>   12/19/2016 12:08 AM  by No presence informationNo presence
>   informationSystem Account

From Upgrade and migration I'm also getting these errors that required upgrade immediately, but my other 2 servers in the farm has same configuration as above but they are not getting these kind of errors, may I please know what can I do now??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check all details at [Health Analyzer Issue: Product/patch installation or server upgrade required](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/11/21/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one server is out of sync. There are couple of possibilities for it.

- Somebody delete the patches/msi files from the system drives.
- or sometime server is out of sync with config DB

Easy fix in many sitution is run the following command on the complaining server

```
Get-SPProduct -Local
```

If it did not fix the issue then you have to try to install the December 2014 CU on the bad server and re run the config wizard

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, May I please know what happens with Get-SPProduct -Local command?

Comment: read this https://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/

Comment: Thank you so much sir.
I will go through the link and update you soon.